# Jack and Jenny's marbles

Tags: arithmetic

Im really struggling with this assignment from puzzles and logic. I think I know the method, but the teacher didn't tell us in class. I just would really appreciate you tell me which method would work, I would look it up if you have no time.

So here is the paragraph:

Jenny and Jack each started out with the same number of marbles. After, Jenny bought 35 more and Jack lost 15, they had 100 marbles between them. How many marbles did they each have initially?

I think I should solve the following equation:

$$(35+x)+(y-15)=100$$

Please comment as fast as you can!

Comment: They had or have? Did they have 100 marbles between them before the gaining and losing, or after?

Answer (score 3):

It also mentioned they started with the same amount, and thus $x=y$

$$(35+x)+(x-15)=100$$

Comment: Doesn't matter answered it already, its 40